# Transforming Wordpress feed with XSLT

Tags: wordpress, xslt

I need some help transforming a Wordpress feed with XSLT. I get an error when I apply this code to the feed.

Code:

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="content:encoded"/>
```

Error:

```
Invalid XSLT: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: content
```

Feed:

```
<content:encoded>
<![CDATA[
  <p>Welcome to the Workforce Development Division of Northern Virginia Community College 
  On this blog you will find out information about our program.  This will include class 
  updates, news, events and other pertinent information.  We hope you enjoy this blog.  Feel.
  </p>
]]>
</content:encoded>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified the namespace URI for **content** in your xsl declaration?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:content="????">
```

The URI for the **content** namespace should match the one that should have been specified in the XML feed.